# Trouble Creating SSL Certificate

Tags: linux, webserver, ssl-certificate, sunone

I'm trying to create a self-signed certificate for a test web server running Sun Webserver 6.1 using certutil. I am open to using keytool or openssl if someone has better instructions which work with Sun Webserver.

Here are the commands that I use:

```
certutil -S -P "https-myWebapp-" -d . -n myCA -s "CN=myWebserver.com CA,OU=myCompany,C=US" -x -t "CT,CT,CT" -m 102 -v 301 -5
```

and I select option 5 - SSL CA and "yes" to the critical extension question. The CA is created successfully. Now that I have created the certificate authority, I try to sign the actual cert with the following command:

```
certutil -S -P "https-myWebapp-" -d . -n myServer -s "CN=myWebserver.com,C=US" -c myCA -t "u,u,u"  -m 102 -v 300 -5
```

At the certutil prompt, I select option 1 to create a SSL server with critical extensions enabled. This produces the following error:

```
certutil: could not obtain certificate from file: You are attempting to import a cert with the same issuer/serial as an existing cert, but that is not the same cert.
```

What did I do wrong? I think that I may have a failed SSL certificate, but I get the following when running certutil -L -d . -P "https-myWebapp-"

```
Certificate Nickname                                      Trust Attributes
                                                          SSL,S/MIME,JAR/XPI
myCA                                                      CTu,Cu,Cu
```

Answer (score 1):

In the second command, I needed to change the -m property to a new serial id number.

That fixed the error message and created the certificate.